# MGSplitViewController on iPad with UISearchBar

Tags: uisearchbar, ipad

I use a MGSplitViewController in tab bar. As a master controller I use a UINavigationController with a UISearchBar with the scope bar.
When I click on the search text field first time everything is ok, but when I cancel searching and then click on the search bar again, the scope bar disappears but the height of the search bar didn't change (is so big like with the scope bar) and the text field move to the center of the bar. This occurs only in landscape. When I make it from popover, everything works.
Had anyone this problem?